# Difference between EF and EX in CTL

Tags: logic, formal-proofs

I don't understand the difference between `EF` and `EX` in [CTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_tree_logic). The [tutorial](http://nusmv.fbk.eu/NuSMV/tutorial/v26/tutorial.pdf#page=14) says almost the same about the two (but they do give different results in a running program)

> EF p
>   , on the other hand, requires than there
>   exists
>   some path (
>   E
>   ) that
>   eventually in the future satisfies
>   p

and for EX

> EX p
>   , requiring that condition
>   p
>   is true in all or in some of the next states
>   reachable from the current state.

Could you help me understand maybe if you provide good examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: In CTL, $\mathsf{EF\,} p$ considers the truth of $p$ in every future state of a computation path, including the current one, whereas $\mathsf{EX\,} p$  only considers the truth of $p$ in the next state (the one that comes right after the current one). That is, $\mathsf{F}$ as in "future" and $\mathsf{X}$ as in "next," with the caveat that in CTL the present is included in the future.

Longer answer: The semantics of CTL is defined on Kripke structures.  We say that $\mathsf{EF\,} p$ holds at state $s$ of structure $K$, written

$$ K,s \models \mathsf{EF\,} p \enspace,$$

if and only if there exists an infinite path $\pi$ in $K$ that starts at $s$ and such that some state along $\pi$ satisfies $p$; that is, there exists $s'$ along this path such that $K,s' \models p$.

Translating $\mathsf{EF\,} p$ into English, we often say "$p$ may eventually happen."  CTL being a *temporal* logic, it is customary to interpret states reached from a state following transitions of $K$ as *future* states.

For $\mathsf{EX\,} p$, the definition is that $K,s \models \mathsf{EX\,} p$ if and only if there is an infinite path $\pi$ in $K$ starting from $s$ and such that the *immediate successor* state of $s$ along $\pi$ satisfies $p$.  If the *immediate* successor is $s'$, then we write this as $K,s' \models p$.

We use $K,s \models \mathsf{EF\,} p$ when we don't want to impose a bound on the number of transitions it may take for $p$ to take place.  We just claim that a state where $p$ holds is reachable in $K$ from $s$.

If we want to exclude the current state from consideration, we write $\mathsf{EX\,}\mathsf{EF\,} p$.  As an another example, if we want to say that from $s$ it always *remains possible* to reach a state where $p$ holds, no matter what path is followed, we write something equivalent to

$$ K,s \models \neg \mathsf{EF\,} \neg \mathsf{EF\,} p \enspace. $$

This may also be written more concisely as

$$ K,s \models \mathsf{AG\,} \mathsf{EF\,} p \enspace, $$

as you have already seen, or will see soon if you continue to explore CTL.
We may read either formula as follows: No matter what path we follow from $s$, we are always in a state from which there exist a path to a state where $p$ holds.

We use $\mathsf{EX}$ when we want to specify a bound on the number of transitions.  For instance, to say that $p$ occurs in one to three transitions along some path that starts from $s$, we may write

$$ K, s \models \mathsf{EX\,} (p \vee \mathsf{EX\,} (p \vee \mathsf{EX\,} p)) \enspace.$$

Final note: if we interpret transitions in the Kripke structure as moving to the "next time" we are inherently assuming that time is discretized: that there is a notion of "next time instant."  This notion is essential for the definition of $\mathsf{EX}$, whereas we could still define $\mathsf{EF}$ without that notion, though it wouldn't be classic CTL any more.